# Pci expansion card does not seem to fit exactly on the slot. Is this how should it really look like?

Tags: pci, expansion-cards

I bought a PCI expansion card for my old desktop to increase the number of usb ports.

When I tried to install it, I was able to put it in but for it does not fill the whole slot. Its like missing half an inch that is not occupied on the slot on the last part. Is that how it should look like?

It did not worked when I tried to access a flash drive. And it even destroyed the flash drive since I am not able to access it anymore.

I though I bought the correct part since the document for dell optiplex 9010 says its just a PCI connector. And this expansion card that I bought also says PCI card.

So I think my question is, when you try to install the pci expansion card, is it not supposed to fill the whole slot like when you are installing a memory stick?

Sorry for the lack of details. Here is the info from the manual. [image]!

It clearly says number 11 that it is a pci connector. That is where i tried to plug it in.

And here's the item that I bought. https://shopee.ph/product/60228355/1604652856?smtt=0.0.9

Also, here's the actual photo of the PCI card that I bought. it shows it is close to 3 inches. But when I measured the PCI slot, it is about 3.5 inches (sorry I'm too ashamed to show you guys the inside of my computer) . But yeah, I can definitely insert it, the groove matches but it just doesn't fill up the PCI slot.

[image]

Maybe I really bought some garbage piece and should just move on?

Comment: Can you add links to the product, and/or a photo of the card in the PCI slot?

Comment: PCI is over 2 years old and hasn’t been on modern motherboards for nearly that long.  You sure you are dealing with a PCI card?

Comment: PCI or PCI Express? PCI Express cards could fill just part of the slot and that's okay, they're just not using all the lanes available. PCI card in a PCI Express slot, however, would probably release the magic smoke.

Comment: I still want to see a photo of the card itself. It should fit the whole PCI slot. I recieved a damaged PCI NIC once. The last part (the short section) of the connector was broken off. I wonder if you have a similar problem.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The evidence tells us all we need. I also updated the answer, but it would be great if the question gets reopened

Answer (score 2):

There are PCI-Express with different bandwidths. See:

[image]
image source: overclock.net

USB expension cards typically use 1x or 4x slots  and thus are very small compared to say... a Graphics card.

Your motherboard can have a 4x and 16x slot while you have a 1x slot card, and your question is: it fits but is loose. Is this a problem?

No. These cards are backwards compatible. The first connectorpins at the fixed group (right in the image) is always the same, the pins after that are for the data transfer. As long as you position the first segment (the part on the right) properly, the card will work. Just make sure you also fasten the screw so the card does not come out.

This is of course not to be mistaken by the old PCI (white) ports/cards, but these are fundamentally different that the card should not even fit. At least, a PCI-Express card may actually fit on an old PCI slot. If that is the case, it will damage the card and it won't work. Do note, it should not fit as the metal of the card would hit the plastic of the PCI slot, but if for some reason your card is different, that's the only thing I can think of that you could force it in.

See here:
[image]

Notice how that short connector is on the opposite side, and how the card simply does not align? You would not get the card in the case, so its safe to assume that you are talking about  PCI-Express cards here.

EDIT: Based on the new information:

You have old PCI card with old PCI slot, so its a 1-on-1 match and works like any card. It is true that if you don't fasten the card itself with a screw to the case, it may feel loose. That is normal. It is the right card for the right slot.

Comment: they posted a link to the card, its the old PCI

Comment: Thanks @Moab I've edited my answer accordingly. The question could be reopened again I think.

Comment: thank you @LPChip. I will try to reinstall it again after my shift since it makes my computer go a bit crazy. I'll check if it needs to be screwed. earlier when I tried to install the card, my monitor became unrecognizable and can only go for 800 x 600 display. I'm not sure why that happened.

Answer (score 1):

A photograph of the card would have helped.

But is sounds like you are confusing PCI (old, but still found on some computers) and PCIe (current).

Sounds like you have a short 1x or 4x PCIe card.
These will fit and work fine in a longer (8x or 16x) PCIe slot.

If the bracket on the end of the card fits the space in the backplane of the PC case you are fine.
(A PCI card won't fit in a PCIe slot and vice-versa. The spacing between the slot on the motherboard and the backplane is different.)

PS. On most motherboards the PCI slots (if any) are made of white plastic and the PCIe slots are black or blue. But don't trust on that as some manufacturers use different colors.. Check the manual to be absolutely sure.

Comment: they posted a link to the card, its the old PCI

Comment: @moab I see that now. I still want to see a photo of the card itself. It should fit the whole slot.

Comment: @Tonny, thanks for you answer. I posted additional images.